# Calling Parent function from Child Component is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I was unable to call a function `handler` from a child component even i have passed the parent function during `render`. This function is called when the user click on the icon header and at least it will alert a text `"in handler"` but it just doing nothing.

A Child actually a constant of `createBottomTabNavigator` and it will call another component which is `ChildScreen` as a screen.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
    this.state = {
     someVar: someValue
    }
  }

  handler(e) {
    alert('in handler!');

    this.setState({
      someVar: someValue
    })
  }

  render() {
    return <Child screenProps={this.state} handler={this.handler} />
  }
}

const Child = createBottomTabNavigator(
{
  Home: {
    screen: ChildScreen,
    navigationOptions:{
      title: "Child",
      ..
      },
    },
  ...
})

class ChildScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return ...
      <Header
        ...
        rightComponent={{ icon: 'translate', onPress: () => this.props.handler }}
        ...
      />
  }
}
```

Comment: you have done referencing in place of calling

Comment: can you explain this return ...
      <Header
        ...
        rightComponent={{ icon: 'translate', onPress: () => {this.props.handler} }}
        ...
      />

Comment: its `Header` from `react-native-elements`

Comment: so is it reactjs or react-native

Comment: `react-native` and i think its related to `reactjs` too O.o

Comment: just updated it.

Answer (score 0):

You're not invoking the function,
This should solve the problem

```
  <Header
    ...
    rightComponent={{ icon: 'translate', onPress: () => this.props.handler() }}
    ...
  />
```

or 
if you call the function in curly braces you need to return it like this

```
 <Header
...
rightComponent={{ icon: 'translate', onPress: () =>{return this.props.handler() }}
...
/>
```

Since ChildSceen is not the direct child of Parent,
You need to pass the props from Child to ChildScreen like this

```
const Child = createBottomTabNavigator(
{
   Home: {
      screen: (props) => <ChildScreen {...props} />
   ...
   }
}
```

Comment: tried it bro. it give me `undefined is not a function` for `onPress: () => {this.props.handler()}`

Comment: first explain your child component

Comment: your updated answer is still not invoking the function
did you try onPress: () => this.props.handler()  ??

Comment: tried it. if i put `this.props.handler()` it will show the error, if i just use `this.props.handler` it will do nothing. i think this is related to navigator issue.

Comment: @ggDeGreat sorry i hadn't seen your edit completely, in case you haven't found the solution yet, you can try he updated answer.

Comment: `screen: (props) => <ChildScreen {...props} />` only worked for parent state props but not for a function.

Comment: @ggDeGreat did u try  onPress: () => this.props.handler() ?